# Open report link URL in new blank window

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, hyperlink

I have dynamic links in my report and when the link is clicked I want it to open in `target="_blank"`.

I have tried the following, but I must be missing a single or double quote somewhere because I am having no luck. The parameters may be throwing me off. For example, I tried these:

```vb
="javascript:void(window.open('http://server/folder/filename.aspx?ds='& Parameters!UserName.Value & '&bu=' & Fields!Business_Unit.Value & '&in=' & Fields!Item_No.Value,'_blank'))"
```

And:

```vb
="http://server/folder/filename.aspx?ds="& Parameters!UserName.Value & "&bu="& Fields!Business_Unit.Value & "&in=" & Fields!Item_No.Value &rc:LinkTarget=_blank
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://server/folder/filename.aspx?ds=" & Parameters!UserName.Value & "&bu=" & Fields!Business_Unit.Value & "&in=" & Fields!Item_No.Value & "','_blank'))"
```

Comment: In what specific way is it failing?

Comment: Added this to the "Go to URL" expression and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Use below script in Jump to URL box.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/
   ReportViewer.aspx?/TestFolder/TestReportName&rs:Command=Render&Parameter1=" &
   Parameters!Date1.Value & "&Paramerter2=" & Parameters!dayname.Value & 
   "&Parameter3=" & Fields!Booknumber.Value & "&Parameter4=" & 
   Fields!TopicOrderby.Value & "','_blank'))"
```

Please double check `servername`, `reportname`, `parameternames` (case sensitive).

Answer (score 3):

Try this on report access URL

```
&rc:LinkTarget=_blank
```

And the option on your report field must look something like `="http://yourURL.com"`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to either use window.open, *or* target

`<a href="http://..." target="_blank" />`
or
`javascript:void(window.open('http://...'));`

Not both.  If you are building your URL, then build it before injecting it into the document.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
="javascript:void window.open(" &"'" & Globals!ReportServerUrl & "/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" & Globals!ReportFolder & "/SubReportWithMemberInfoUsedByWaiverFinance&rc:Parameters=False&RepParameterSet=50,>64,E," & Fields!YYYYMM.Value & "','_blank')"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
="javascript:void window.open(" &"'" & Globals!ReportServerUrl & "/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" & Globals!ReportFolder & "/SubReportWithMemberInfoUsedByWaiverFinance&rc:Parameters=False&RepParameterSet=50,>64,E," & Fields!YYYYMM.Value & "','_blank')"
```

Works well I tested in SSRS 2014  ( That extra parenthesis between VOID and WINDOW is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

set

```
HyperlinkTarget="_blank"
```

of `<rsweb:ReportViewer>` element in your asp page

[more description](https://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/Contents/Item/Display/87)