# SSRS - Go To URL - Adding JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open report link URL in new blank window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143295/open-report-link-url-in-new-blank-window)

I am using SSRS 2008.

I have a text box on my report and when I change the Action property to "Go to URL" and I add in http://www.example.com it does work. But if I try using JavaScript that is suppose to work it does not.

I have tried all of these and none of these work.

- javascript:void(window.open('http://www.example.com'))
- javascript:history.go(-1)
- javascript:void(window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank'))
- javascript:history.back(1)

Answer (score -2):

I don't agree with your statement: "that is suppose to work".

IMO javascript in Report Actions is an "technique" (hack), not supported by the product or documented by the vendor:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157159(v=sql.100).aspx

It might or might not work depending on all kinds of factors.

Good luck!