# SSRS field as http link

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report which displays some data fields as http links. Sometimes there is no value (it is blank) but it still creates a http link.

So in the TextBox properties of the field I have this expression set under Action -> Go to URL

```
="http://myserver:Id@@" & Fields!IDNo.Value
```

That works just fine when there is a value but how can I tell it to ignore creating the http link when the `IDNo.Value` is blank or null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an expression that sets the URL as `Nothing` for values you don't want to use as URLs.

So in your example you can use an expression under **Select URL:**

[image]

like:

```
=IIf(Not IsNothing(Fields!IDNo.Value) And Fields!IDNo.Value <> ""
  , "http://myserver:Id@@" & Fields!IDNo.Value
  , Nothing)
```

i.e. only add a URL to the textbox if the row field is not null and is not blank.

Comment: One last thing, how do I make the link open in a new window?

Comment: Not something I've ever really had to do, but I understand you can embed some Javascript in the action link to achieve this... This SO questions explains in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143295/open-report-link-url-in-new-blank-window

Comment: Might just leave it as that can mess up the export to Excel

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 =IIf(IsNothing(Fields!IDNo.Value),
 False,
 "http://myserver:Id@@" & Fields!IDNo.Value)
```